# Составной (Пользовательский) тип в OpenOffice

Tags: sql, postgresql, vba, open-office

Есть в postgresql составной тип:

```
Create type CompLaLaLa AS (
    Name character varying,
    Count numeric
);
```

И таблица:

```
CREATE TABLE "LaLaLa" (
    "ID" serial NOT NULL,
    "Сomposition" CompLaLaLa[] NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT LaLaLa_pk PRIMARY KEY ("ID")
);
```

Я подключил БД к OpenOffice и при выборках:

```
select "Сomposition" from "LaLaLa"
```

Выводит пустые ячейки. Если to_json("Сomposition"), то просто тип Object выводит. Как считать данный тип в OpenOffice?

Сам запрос в макросе:

```
sub main
     Dim db as Object
     db = connect_to_database("postgre")
     SelectPrixod(db,30)
     disconnect_from_database(db)
end sub

Sub SelectPrixod(dbName as Object,ID as integer)
     Dim pSql as String
     Dim i as Integer
     Dim oRowSet as Object
     Dim oResult as String
     oSql = " SELECT ""Composition"" FROM ""LaLaLa"" Where ""ID""=ID; "
     oRowSet = createUnoService("com.sun.star.sdb.RowSet")
     oRowSet.activeConnection = dbName 'Активное подключение
     oRowSet.Command = oSql 'Запрос
     oRowSet.execute 'вызов запроса

     while oRowSet.Next 'бежим 
        oResult = oResult & capitalize (oRowSet.getString(1)) & " " & chr(13)
     wend
     msgbox oResult
End Sub

Function capitalize (iName as String) as String
     Dim wordStart as String
     Dim wordEnd as String
     wordStart = UCase (Mid (iName, 1, 1))
     wordEnd = LCase (Mid (iName, 2))
     capitalize = wordStart & wordEnd
End Function

Function connect_to_database (dbName as String) as Object
     Dim dbContext As Object
     Dim oDataSource As Object
     dbContext = createUnoService("com.sun.star.sdb.DatabaseContext")
     oDataSource = dbContext.getByName(dbName)
     connect_to_database = oDataSource.GetConnection("admin", "Oma") 'подключение к ДБ
End Function

Sub disconnect_from_database (db as Object)
     db.close
     db.dispose()
End Sub
```

Выводит пустоту

Comment: Неужели нет экспертов по openoffice? На конкурс 2 дня =(

Comment: Как подключали? Для чего? Что за конкурс?

Comment: Конкурс здесь, на вопрос =) Подключал через jdbc. Для чего? - Что бы была таблица =)

Comment: Мне бы, более точный ответ =(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не могу утверждать на все 100%, но думаю, что в макросах OpenOffice вы никак не сможете работать с массивами пользовательскими типов данных PostgreSQL. Если задача стоит в формировании электронной таблицы из выборки БД именно с помощью макроса, то ответ на ваш вопрос - никак без изменения структуры БД. Данные ведь можно хранить не в массиве объектов составного типа, а в отдельной таблице:

```
CREATE TABLE LaLaLa (
    id SERIAL NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE Сomposition (
    id SERIAL NOT NULL,
    lalala_id INT NOT NULL,
    name VARCHAR,
    count NUMERIC,
    PRIMARY KEY (id, lalala_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (lalala_id) REFERENCES LaLaLa (id)
);
```

И выбирать потом объединением:

```
select c.* from LaLaLa as l inner join Сomposition as c on l.id = c.lalala_id;
```

Если использование макроса - не самоцель, то можно написать программу на каком-нибудь другом языке, которая будет выполняться самостоятельно, отдельно от OpenOffice, но будет делать то же самое - формировать файл электронной таблицы. В этом случае проблемы работы с массивами пользовательских данных не будет.